# Rotate, skew, scale and resize mask together with object

Tags: fabricjs

fabric.js 2.3.6

I'm trying to duplicate any transformations applied to the object to the mask above it.

I have been able to move the mask around with the object, but any transformations applied to the mask are not working, like `mask.set({ angle: object.angle }).setCoords();`

https://jsfiddle.net/30hj5xk2

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check here:https://jsfiddle.net/o91rv38q/41/

```
    // canvas

let canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
  backgroundColor: "lightgray",
  width: 1280,
  height: 720,
  preserveObjectStacking: true,
  selection: false,
  stateful: true
});

canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "black";
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 2;

canvas.on("path:created", function(options) {
   clip(options.path);
});

function clip(path) {

  canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
  canvas.remove(path);

  let mask = new fabric.Path(path.path, {
    top: object.top,
    left: object.left,
    objectCaching: false,
    strokeWidth:0,
    pathOffset: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
  });

  object.set({
    clipTo: function(ctx) {

        mask.set({ 
                        left: -object.width/2-mask.width/2, 
                        top: -object.height/2-mask.height/2,
                        objectCaching: false
                    });
            mask.render(ctx);

    }
  });

  this.canvas.requestRenderAll();

}

// image

let image = new Image();
let object;

image.onload = function() {

  object = new fabric.Image(image, {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    top: 0,
    left: 0
  });

  canvas.add(object);

};

image.src = "http://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg";
```

**UPDATE**
The problem is not the zoom of the canvas. The problem was that you need to take in consideration the `object.left` and `object.top` before you put the mask on the `object`. I saved right before you put the `mask` on the `object` and used to decrese the `mask.left`and `mask.top`
Check here:http://jsfiddle.net/mariusturcu93/30hj5xk2/10/

**JS**

```
// canvas

let canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
  backgroundColor: "lightgray",
  width: 1280,
  height: 720,
  preserveObjectStacking: true,
  selection: false,
  stateful: true
});

canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "black";
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 2;

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  resize();
});

canvas.on("path:created", function(options) {
   clip(options.path);
});

function resize() {
  let canvasWrapper = document.querySelector(".canvas__wrapper");

  let canvasWrapperWidth = canvasWrapper.offsetWidth;
  let canvasWrapperHeight = canvasWrapper.offsetHeight;
  let canvasWrapperRatio = canvasWrapperWidth / canvasWrapperHeight;

  let canvasZoom = canvas.getZoom();
  let canvasRatio = canvas.getWidth() / canvas.getHeight();

  let scale;

  if (canvasWrapperRatio < canvasRatio) {
    scale = canvasWrapperWidth / canvas.getWidth();
    canvasWrapperHeight = canvasWrapperWidth / canvasRatio;
  } else {
    scale = canvasWrapperHeight / canvas.getHeight();
    canvasWrapperWidth = canvasWrapperHeight * canvasRatio;
  }

  scale *= canvasZoom;

  canvas.setDimensions({
    width: canvasWrapperWidth,
    height: canvasWrapperHeight
  });

  canvas.setViewportTransform([scale, 0, 0, scale, 0, 0]);
  console.log(canvas.viewportTransform);
}

resize();

function clip(path) {

  canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
  canvas.remove(path);

  let scale = canvas.getZoom();

  console.log(scale)

  let mask = new fabric.Path(path.path, {
    top: object.top,
    left: object.left,
    objectCaching: false,
    strokeWidth:0,
    pathOffset: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
  });
    var originalObjLeft = object.left,
  originalObjTop  = object.top;
  object.set({
    clipTo: function(ctx) {

        mask.set({ 
                        left: -object.width/2-mask.width/2-originalObjLeft, 
                        top: -object.height/2-mask.height/2-originalObjTop,
                        objectCaching: false
                    });
            mask.render(ctx);

    }
  });

  canvas.requestRenderAll();

}

// image

let image = new Image();
let object;

image.onload = function() {

  object = new fabric.Image(image, {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    top: 20,
    left: 20
  });

  canvas.add(object);

};

image.src = "http://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg";
```

Comment: This works properly, but my canvas contains some zoom. How could i put it back?

Comment: Nut sure what you want. I put a 1.5 zoom on the canvas and it's still work.Check here:https://jsfiddle.net/mariusturcu93/o91rv38q/46/

Comment: @Marius Turcu, please add some explanation to your answer. What was wrong and what did you fix.

Comment: @MariusTurcu http://jsfiddle.net/30hj5xk2/
Take a look here. The canvas contains a viewportTransform, therefore the mask position is wrong.

Comment: @MariusTurcu The problem is in fact the object containing any transformations. If the object is scaled, the mask will be set in the wrong position. I'm trying to fix.